# tbl_summary message (GT summary)

Tags: datatables, gtsummary

I am receiving this error when trying to produce a simple summary table using GT summary. I am trying to count the number observations of each category by phase for each variable. I have produced many tables using this method but have not come across this message. Google was not helpful. Please let me know your thoughts; code and sample data below.

```
tbl1 %>%
  tbl_summary(tbl1, 
              by = phase,
              type = all_categorical() ~ "categorical",
              missing = "no"
  )
```

[image: Error Message]

```
structure(list(X = 1:20, col1 = c("Escherichia", "Candida", "Candida", 
"Candida", "Candida", "Candida", "Candida", "Pseudomonas", "Candida", 
"Escherichia", "Escherichia", "Escherichia", "Candida", "Staphylococcus", 
"Klebsiella", "Pseudomonas", "Candida", "Enterococcus", "Candida", 
"Pseudomonas"), phase = c("BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", 
"BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", 
"BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", "BEFORE", 
"BEFORE", "BEFORE"), Nalidixic.acid_SIR = c("NT", "NT", "NT", 
"NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", 
"NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT"), Amikacin_SIR = c("S", "NT", 
"NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "S", "NT", "NT", "S", "S", "NT", 
"NT", "S", "S", "NT", "NT", "NT", "S"), Amoxicillin.Clavulanate_SIR = c("I", 
"NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "S", "I", 
"NT", "NT", "S", "NT", "NT", "S", "NT", "NT"), Amoxicillin_SIR = c("R", 
"NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "R", "R", 
"NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "S", "NT", "NT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: It looks like you may be passing the data frame tbl1 to the function twice?

Comment: Hey! Are you the main author of the tutorial? Thank you so much for all that you have done! What you stated fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was running passing the function through tbl1 twice. Below is the code I used to fixed it

```
tbl2 <- tbl1 %>%
  tbl_summary( 
              by = phase,
              type = all_categorical() ~ "categorical",
              missing = "no"
  )
```